# a2lix TranslationFormBundle AND Gedmo Doctrine Extension Translatable with just one Translation table

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, a2lix-translation

I am trying to use the a2lix TranslationFormBundle  ( https://github.com/a2lix/TranslationFormBundle ) with a Symfony2 project.
I have been looking at docs and specifically at this demo: https://github.com/a2lix/Demo/tree/master/src/A2lix/DemoTranslationBundle

I noticed all examples in both the doc and the demo use specific translation tables (end entity) for each translatable entity, as set in the class annotation with

```
@Gedmo\TranslationEntity(class="A2lix\DemoTranslationBundle\Entity\ProductGedmoTranslation")
```

My idea was to stay with just one table, like the ext_translations table that the Gedmo Doctrine Extension Translatable creates and manages.

Is this possible or does the TranslationFormBundle absolutely need separate tables?
Does anyone have a working example?

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the current implementation of TranslationFormBundle, you need separate tables. Use an only one ext_translations table is not plan.

Comment: Hello, would it be possible using another Bundle than Stof's? like KNP or others?

Comment: @jugali-lakota yes, this is the case of last versions >=2.0

Comment: Thanks for replying. I've already switch many entity to the separate tables approch. Sad. Anyway, could you provide me link 'cause I used KNP and I make many entityTranslation. It's what I discover from the official tuto. Thanks,